# Can't import pillow in the flask project

Tags: python, flask, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make an image gallery page with flask, I need to use pillow to resize the images to show them as thumbnails but when I try to import pillow I get an error.

I am using python3.5 and I didn't install pillow on top of the PILL
I am using a ubuntu server that runs apache2.
All packages are installed in a virtualenv.
I tried to reinstall pillow, also tried different versions of it still does not working.
It works when I try it seperately but not working with flask project.
Also pip freeze shows that I have Pillow==6.1.0

I used this to install pillow:

```
pip install Pillow
```

This line gives error:

```
from PIL import Image
```

This is the error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
from flaskapp import app as application
File "/var/www/flaskapp/flaskapp/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from PIL import Image
File "/var/www/flaskapp/flaskapp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 95, in <module>
from . import _imaging as core

ImportError: cannot import name _imaging
```

Comment: Related question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340698/importerror-cannot-import-name-imaging

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name \_imaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340698/importerror-cannot-import-name-imaging)

Comment: I am using python3.5 and I didn't install pillow on top of the PILL

Answer (score 0):

Pillow should be uninstalled first, make sure that you delete all the cache files related to pillow in the original path( /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/) where the packages of your python version are stored. Once this is done try re installing the pillow from the beginning.