# Can't find 'Image' after installing Pillow?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-imaging-library, tesseract, python-tesseract

Playing with PDF and images in my virtualenv, and I installed `pdfminer-six`, `pypdf2`, `pytesseract` and `pdf2image` with pip:

```
$python3 -m venv testenv
$source testenv/bin/activate
$pip3 install pdfminer-six 
$pip3 install pypdf2 
$pip3 install pdf2image 
$pip3 install pytesseract
```

but then I ran into these importing errors:

```
$python3

>>> import pytesseract
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/userx/test_dir/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 22, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/home/userx/test_dir/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 94, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/home/userx/test_dir/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/userx/test_dir/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytesseract/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pytesseract import (  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/userx/test_dir/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 24, in <module>
    import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'
```

and

```
>>> from pdf2image import convert_from_path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/userx/test_dir/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdf2image/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .pdf2image import (
  File "/home/userx/test_dir/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 14, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/home/chengx/pdf_text/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 94, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/home/userx/test_dir/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
```

(That said, `from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader` worked well though.)

I then have `Pillow` installed via pip too:

```
$python3 -m pip install Pillow
```

as an attempt to fix the issue, but the import errors didn't go away. Any reason why imaging is still missing? Thank you!

I'm on CentOS8, and this is my current setup:

```
(testenv) [~/test_dir] python --version
Python 3.7.5+
(testenv) [~/test_dir] pip -V
pip 20.2.3 from /home/userx/test_dir/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
(testenv) [~/test_dir] pip list
Package          Version
---------------- --------
cffi             1.14.3
chardet          3.0.4
cryptography     3.1.1
pdf2image        1.14.0
pdfminer.six     20200726
Pillow           7.2.0
pip              20.2.3
pycparser        2.20
PyPDF2           1.26.0
pytesseract      0.3.6
setuptools       41.2.0
six              1.15.0
sortedcontainers 2.2.2
```

Comment: it would really help reproduce the issue if you could share at least the imports section of your script as a snippet clearly.

Comment: Please show the exact code you run and the exact command you use to run it.

Comment: thanks Mar, updated

Comment: Please show a Python example that causes this error. This shouldn't be your entire project. Just make a new .py file with a few lines to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I suggest you google the error to see if someone has already found a solution. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340698/importerror-cannot-import-name-imaging

Comment: lol, the import itself is errorr'ing out, what more example code do you need?

Comment: I tried to reproduce it in python 3.8 to no avail. I suspect it's an issue with Pillow's installation. please try `pip3 install -U Pillow` (with `-U`) in the environment and test it again

Comment: Why do you run `python --version` when you are running `python3` everywhere else?