# Cant import Pillow correctly

Tags: python, import, pip, python-imaging-library

I got a problem with importing Pillow.

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL'
```

Import way:

```
from PIL import Image
```

PIL installation:
pip install Pillow

1. I hasnt try to install Pillow over a PIL installation (default problem i think, after Internet research)
2. I have already reinstalled it with PIP.
3. All other imports working correctly

Have a nice day!

Comment: This surely going to help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil

Comment: I think import Image is not working anymore https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name \_imaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340698/importerror-cannot-import-name-imaging)

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: The duplicate suggested does not solve OP's issue, as discussed under my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pillow [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) mention:

> Pillow >= 2.1.0 no longer supports `import _imaging`. Please use `from PIL.Image import core as _imaging` instead.

Did you try that?

---

Another attempt:

```
pip install -U Pillow
```

Read more in [ImportError: cannot import name _imaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340698/importerror-cannot-import-name-imaging).

PS: PIL is deprecated - Pillow is its replacement.

Comment: Pillow is installed. Module is found but importing not working. If I try to install it: requirements alredy satisfied.

Comment: @Kamajiu did you try my updated answer `pip install -U Pillow`?

Comment: Yes, should have the latest version

Comment: @Kamajiu I see, thank you. Did you read the link in my answer? In the comments they say "pip uninstall pillow pip install pillow was enough". Did you try that? Did you try the deprecation notice in my updated answer?

Comment: I read your link carefully. Reinstallation is not working for me either try to import Image solo. I also havent copy it from another System. Tryed from PIL.Image import core as _imaging , raise same error.