# Cannot import Image from PIL (pillow package)

Tags: python, import, python-imaging-library

I am currently in the process of learning python and its modules/packages. Right now, I am trying to toy with the pillow module. However, I cannot even seem to be able to import it. Whenever I run the following:

```
import sys

sys.path.append(r"c:\users\tfk\appdata\local\program\python\python310\lib\site-packages")
print(sys.path)
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("elzero-pillow.png")
```

I get an error message stating that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "c:\Users\TFK\Documents\Tests\test.py", line 7, in 
from PIL import Image
File "c:\users\tfk\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 82, in 
from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '*imaging' from 'PIL' (c:\users\tfk\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\PIL_*init**.py)

I tried all possible combinations in the documentation, but to no end. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that you should do `from PIL import _imaging`? According to the [tutorial](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html) you might want: `from PIL import Image; img = Image.open("elzero-pillow.png")`

Comment: What version of Python and PIL are you using? How did you install them? How are you invoking your script? All these can affect the success of using PIL. Also, why do you think `_imaging` exists in `PIL`?

Comment: @Matthias Exactly! That's what I found odd. I put just as the code shows from PIL import Image, yet the error I get is about _imaging

Comment: @PeterWood  For Python, I am using 3.10.12, and for pillow, it is 10.1.0. I installed pillow via pip after updating it to the latest version. I am running my script via VScode's terminal

Comment: @ProgrammingLearner2023 which Python is VS Code's terminal using?

Comment: Try `print(sys.executable)` and also show output from`print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 0):

Your current code actually throws this error `AttributeError: module 'PIL._imaging' has no attribute 'open'`. I'm not sure why you commented out `from PIL import Image` because that's what I'm guessing you need. Try this:

```
from PIL import Image as core
img = core.open("C:\\Users\\John Piper\\Desktop\\mail.png")
```

You can examine details of your image object and also diplay your image using the code below:

```
print(img.format, img.size, img.mode)  # Examine details of your image object
img.show()      # Display your image
```

See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html for more information on how to do other things with your image.

Comment: I still get this error:
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (c:\users\tfk\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py)

Comment: what code did you run?

Comment: I should maybe state that I have this written before the above code, as without it, python doesn't see the module, and I can't import it:

import sys

sys.path.append(
    r"c:\users\tfk\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages"
)

Comment: I ran:
from PIL import Image as core
img = core.open("C:\\Users\\John Piper\\Desktop\\mail.png") 
and I of course changed the url to the image's location, which is the same as the py file to "pillow-image.png"

Comment: Can you try the answers here especially the accepted answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340698/importerror-cannot-import-name-imaging

Comment: Please put all your code, and how you ran it, and all your results and errors in your question where it can be formatted properly and found easily. Thank you.

Comment: @journpy I applied all of them to no success.

Comment: I must add that I had no problem using Pylint, another package, but this one is impossible to work with.